Can TCP Packets Be Spoofed? How to handle fake SYN requests / identify who is responsible for these packets?
Long story short, my server's system load is off the charts, but nothing is taxing the CPU script or program wise.  It appears that it is under a TCP Syn flood attack, but I cannot figure out how to mitigate this.  Amazon (15.185.242.226 is on their network) says the traffic is spoofed and their servers are not responsible.  I was under the impression it's impossible to spoof TCP packets?  Is this not the case?
Here's some packets I've captured (exported from WireShark in text format):
8671 514.584019 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 28199 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18672 514.584119 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 28199 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18673 514.676551 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 13932 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=128 SACK_PERM
18674 514.676652 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 13932 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18675 514.811716 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 21881 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=128 SACK_PERM
18676 514.811803 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 21881 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18677 515.191345 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 36038 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18678 515.191471 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 36038 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18679 515.225413 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 48681 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18680 515.225497 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 48681 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18681 515.592425 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 28199 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18682 515.688435 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 13932 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18683 515.816424 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 21881 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18684 516.175386 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 50006 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=8 SACK_PERM
18685 516.175496 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 50006 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18686 516.200452 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 36038 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18687 516.232434 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 48681 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18688 516.808050 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 22042 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18689 516.808192 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 22042 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18690 517.091624 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 37726 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18691 517.091729 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 37726 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18692 517.192419 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 50006 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18693 517.339002 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 21726 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18694 517.339110 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 21726 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18695 517.361467 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 9341 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18696 517.361535 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 9341 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18697 517.555949 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 60616 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=8 SACK_PERM
18698 517.556041 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 60616 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18699 517.606349 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 21806 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18700 517.606422 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 21806 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18701 517.608439 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 28199 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18702 517.704419 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 13932 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18703 517.832414 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 22042 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18704 517.832438 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 21881 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18705 517.854558 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 17447 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 SACK_PERM
18706 517.854664 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 17447 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18707 517.920031 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 23488 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18708 517.920107 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 23488 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18709 517.945919 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 52349 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18710 517.946000 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 52349 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18711 517.999858 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 2613 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18712 517.999935 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 2613 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18713 518.120330 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 37726 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18714 518.157828 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 13501 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18715 518.157911 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 13501 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18716 518.216424 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 36038 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18717 518.235220 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 58936 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18718 518.235320 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 58936 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18719 518.248417 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 48681 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18720 518.275138 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 36902 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18721 518.275223 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 36902 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18722 518.330857 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 33525 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18723 518.330946 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 33525 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18724 518.344418 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 21726 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18725 518.348391 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 33424 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=128 SACK_PERM
18726 518.348440 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 33424 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18727 518.376414 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 9341 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18728 518.401689 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 52399 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=8 SACK_PERM
18729 518.401764 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 52399 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18730 518.514847 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 35628 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18731 518.514928 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 35628 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18732 518.568439 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 60616 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18733 518.632421 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 21806 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18734 518.658273 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 2306 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18735 518.658364 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 2306 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18736 518.734487 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 10539 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18737 518.734565 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 10539 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18738 518.747410 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 14212 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18739 518.747492 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 14212 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18740 518.753608 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 54384 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18741 518.753691 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 54384 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18742 518.856415 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 17447 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18743 518.920327 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 23488 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18744 518.947887 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 6508 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18745 518.947971 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 6508 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18746 518.952322 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 52349 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18747 519.016413 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 2613 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18748 519.154491 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 10176 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18749 519.154597 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 10176 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18750 519.169035 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 56679 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18751 519.169104 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 56679 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18752 519.176421 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 13501 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18753 519.208416 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 50006 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18754 519.240339 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 58936 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18755 519.277394 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 31480 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=128 SACK_PERM
18756 519.277487 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 31480 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18757 519.304417 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 36902 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18758 519.312068 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 52940 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18759 519.312151 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 52940 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18760 519.336380 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 33525 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18761 519.368411 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 33424 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18762 519.432414 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 52399 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18763 519.462861 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 37589 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 SACK_PERM
18764 519.462947 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 37589 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18765 519.467416 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 34855 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=128 SACK_PERM
18766 519.467498 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 34855 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18767 519.474924 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 65365 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18768 519.475001 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 65365 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18769 519.515416 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 6733 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=8 SACK_PERM
18770 519.515503 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 6733 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18771 519.528419 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 35628 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18772 519.619337 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 45158 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18773 519.619414 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 45158 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18774 519.647835 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 64824 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18775 519.647915 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 64824 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18776 519.683761 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 17126 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18777 519.683853 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 17126 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18778 519.688386 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 2306 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18779 519.711985 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 4048 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=64 SACK_PERM
18780 519.712068 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 4048 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18781 519.752327 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 443 → 14212 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18782 519.752340 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 10539 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18783 519.784414 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 54384 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18784 519.794165 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 30993 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1436 WS=512 SACK_PERM
18785 519.794248 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 80 → 30993 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18786 519.848408 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 22042 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18787 519.976385 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 6508 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128
18788 520.027486 15.185.242.226 {MY_SERVERS_IP} TCP 66 20394 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM
18789 520.027596 {MY_SERVERS_IP} 15.185.242.226 TCP 66 443 → 20394 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM WS=128

So, how do I keep my Linux Ubuntu 20.04 server from working so hard when processing bogus SYN requests?  How do I determine the true origin of this attack?  Who is responsible?  What can I do to mitigate the impact it has on my server's CPUs?
Any help would be appreciated.

There's ~1 per sec according to your logs. That's not a lot. Are you sure this is your problem?

Surely one can spoof the IP address in single TCP packets. What is much harder though is to establish a TCP connection because for this one would be able to either observe the answer or correctly guess the initial sequence number used by the peer. But for SYN flood this does not matter, since this is the first packet in a TCP connection and the attacker does not care about actually establishing a TCP connection.

@vidarlo - yes, it gets overloaded from processing the retransmissions.  There is nothing else I have been able to identify for the high server load.  It is always high when this attack is going on.  It comes from one IP address for about 10 minutes, but then the same attack comes from another IP address on the 15.0.0.0/8 network randomly... been going on for the past several weeks now.  It's very annoying my server is trying to handle these requests with it going nowhere ever (no ack is ever made from these requests)... and it looks like it works hard retransmitting...

I'm not the only one reporting these IPs either:  https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/15.185.242.242  --- banning the ips via iptables rules works, but not when the attack shifts to another 15.x IP :( --- I'd like to know if there's a way to determine if what Amazon's abuse team is saying (they're not the source) is true.

You can spoof any IP address with any protocol. It's just that TCP won't ever work with a spoofed address since the SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK handshake could never complete - but for SYN flooding that doesn't matter.
You're lucky as all spoofed packets use the same source address. Simple configure your firewall to drop those packets with source 15.185.242.226 and destination port 80 TCP. Even a switch with ACLv4 port could be used.

Yes, but Amazon is adamant that it is not coming from their address (15.185.242.226) despite my packet capturing showing that is the source.  It's possible this source address is spoofed, correct?  In which case, there's no way to know who is responsible?

Yes, it's possible. There's nothing you can do to find the source yourself, but your ISP may have more insight, at least which peering partner transmits those packets.
